# Como colocar pontinho ou marcadores de localização no mapa

Tags: javascript

Como posicionar aqueles "marcadores" no meu mapa, passando a Longitude e a Latitude?

Esse é meu script HTML do mapa:

```
<div class="map-canvas" data-opt=' + ' {"txtLatitude":' +
this.Latitude + ',"txtLongitude":' + this.Longitude + '}' + '
style="display: block;width: 750px;height: 300px;"></div>
```

E o JavaScript:

```
var map;
$('[href*="#mapa-"]').click(function () {
    var $map = $('.map-canvas', $(this).attr('href'));
    map = new google.maps.Map($map.get(0), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng($map.data('opt').txtLatitude, $map.data('opt').txtLongitude)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [`documentação`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=pt-br#Markers) na seção Marcadores.

O construtor `google.maps.Marker` pega um único literal do objeto *Marker* options que especifica as propriedades inicial do marcador. Os campos a seguir são particularmente importantes e comumente definidos durante a construção do marcador.

- `position`: (*obrigatório*) especifica um LatLng que identifica a localização inicial do marcador.
- `map` (*opcional*): especifica o objeto Map no qual o marcador deve ser posicionado.

No construtor `Marker`, você deve especificar o mapa no qual o marcador deve ser adicionado. Se você **não especificar esse argumento, o marcador será criado, mas não será anexado (ou exibido) no mapa**. Você poderá adicionar o marcador posteriormente, chamando o método **`setMap()`** do marcador.

Exemplo(*retirado da documentação*):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.212355602107472,-44.20234468749999);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Meu ponto personalizado"
  });
```